# Haskell - profiling throws exception when using readProcess

Tags: haskell, exception, profiling, ghc

I've started profiling an algorithm I developed, and I've come across a confusing exception.

My program makes a call to an external process. I am using readProcess from System.Process for this call. When I build (ghc 7.8.4) without the -prof flag, the program runs great without any exceptions. When I use the -prof flag, and then execute with +RTS -xc -RTS, I get exceptions at every readProcess occurrence.

I've whittled the code down to a simple Linux-based example.

ProfTest.hs:

```
module Main where

import System.Process
import Control.Exception

main = catch (readProcess "cat" [] "foo" >>= putStrLn)
             (\e -> putStrLn $ show (e :: SomeException))
```

Then build/run as follows:

```
$ ghc -prof ProfTest.hs
$ ./ProfTest +RTS -xc
*** Exception (reporting due to +RTS -xc): (THUNK_1_0), stack trace: 
  Main.CAF
Hello
```

What causes this exception?

The simple solution is to replace the -xc flag with -p or another option which doesn't dump the exception stack. But I'm confused why monitoring for exceptions causes an exception in this instance.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As far as I can tell `-xc` will report exceptions regardless of whether they are caught or not. The same behaviour occurs with just `main = readProcess "cat" [] "foo"`. And with `main = throw (ErrorCall "..") \`catch\` (\(ErrorCall e) -> ..)`. I would assume this "Exception" is coming from deep inside `readProcess`. Note that your exception handler *never* catches an exception (well, if it finds the program "cat" at least). The reported exception isn't otherwise visible to you, the user, through regular means.

Comment: @user2407038 - you make an interesting point about -xc halting execution even when a user thrown exception is immediately caught. Perhaps the profiler can't differentiate between caught and uncaught exceptions?

Comment: I don't think it halts execution - only if the error is actually uncaught. Either it cannot or chooses not to differentiate. I have not been able to find anywhere in the docs if this intended behaviour or not. To be honest I'd never used this feature before, but I've known about it and I always assumed it meant "print the stack trace only if the exception is uncaught". This just seems like the obvious thing for it to do. Perhaps you should consider opening a ticket, if just to clarify in the documentation the behaviour of this feature.

Comment: @user2407038 - it does seem that the program continues to run, but I know it prevents the .prof file from being generated (which is why I was running it to begin with). Perhaps I will open a ticket if no one comes along with a good explanation. Thanks!

Comment: "it prevents the .prof file from being generated" Very strange. It is seeming more and more like a bug. Best of luck, and if you even figure it out feel free to come back and answer your own question for future generations.